# How to format double value as price without currency sign and with special case for no decimals

Tags: c#, .net

I want to string format a double value - a product price - with two decimals when the price is eg. 12.99, and with a ",-" when the price is 12.00. Is that possible using the ToString() extension in C# .NET?

I have tried

```
price.ToString(@"#,0.00;-#,0.00;0\,-");
```

and this gives me "12.99" just fine. But 12.00 shows as "12.00", and I would prefer it to be "12,-". I use groups in the above statement to separate positive, negative and zero numbers.

Can this be done without doing if/else logic in the code?

Cheers
Jens

Comment: Maybe regular expression could do the trick?

Comment: How about price.ToString(@"#,0.00;-#,0.00;0\,-").Replace(".00", ",-") ?

Comment: @Nikhil {0:C0} defeats the purpose, as I don't want currency sign in the string.

Comment: @Fabjan Good suggestion, if the logic can't be incorporated in the format string.

Comment: this question is not duplicate to me

Comment: @JensRud the string Format method still creates a *new* string object so there is no real benefit of using it in terms of better performance compared to .Replace() ...

Comment: look inside `NumberFormatInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price.ToString(@"#,0.00;-#,0.00;0\,-").Replace(".00", ",-");
```